# _.after: a confuse with context

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have extend this function inside Backbone.view

```
toggle: function () {
   var sempurna = _.after(array_obj.length, this.render);
   _.each(array_obj, function (v,k) {
      v.perormSomething();
      delete array_obj[key];
      sempurna();
  }, this);
}
```

And so I thought that I could render the view straight away the loop is completed. But somehow the `this` keyword is refering to `window` instead of the view. How do I point to the intended `this` to view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this` is set to `window` because your are calling `sempurna()` without the dot notation (so without any explicit receiving object).

To fix this you need to `_.bind` (or use the browser native bind if available) your `sempurna` to `this`:

```
toggle: function () {
   var sempurna = _.bind(_.after(array_obj.length, this.render), this);
   _.each(array_obj, function (v,k) {
      v.perormSomething();
      delete array_obj[key];
      sempurna();
  }, this);
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/tX2LK/).

Comment: You could also bind `render` if that makes more sense: `_.after(array_obj.length, _(this.render).bind(this))`.

Comment: `var sempurna = _.after(array_obj.length, _.bind(this.render, this))`. This I just found out after few play around with @muistooshort code. Thanks

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul: `_(x).bind(y)` and `_.bind(x, y)` do the same thing, I tend to use the `_(x).f(y)` form because I find it easier to read.